# combine QAbstractItemModels

Tags: qt, qabstractitemmodel

I have a `map = std::map<std::string, myItemModel *>`, where `myItemModel` inherits `QAbstractItemModel`.

I want now to combine all `myItemModel` in one single `myItemModel` (every other item model would be fine too). 
So that there is one big `myItemModel`.

Is there a 'qt-way' to do this?

Comment: What means "combine all myItemModel in one single myItemModel"? Please clarify.

Comment: I want one boig model which includes all other models.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. The item model isn't a simple collection of items, but defines the functionality. How are you going to combine the functionality?

Answer (score 4):

It can be done, but it's not trivial. It depends on your implementation of `QAbstractItemModel` and that's why it hasn't been done in Qt.

Here are steps to implement a model which is a collection of models:

1. Create a new class inherited from `QAbstractItemModel`
2. Add methods to add other models to that
3. Process all signals from child models which contains indexes (you'll need to change them, look #10)
4. Forward all signals which doesn't contain indexes.
5. Implement `rowCount` and provide a sum of all models rows.
6. Implement `columnCount` and provide a number of columns in your models.
7. Implement `index`, *return createIndex(row, column, NULL);*
8. Implement `parent`, *return QModelIndex();* I hope your models are not trees
9. Implement `data`,`setData` etc.  addressing calls to the right model. Use methods from #10 to convert indexes.
10. Create methods to convert a child model index to a base model index and back.

```
     Example (indexes):  
     BaseModel ChildModel1 ChildModel2
        0,0       0,0         
        1,0       1,0         
        2,0                   0,0
        3,0                   1,0
        4,0                   2,0
```

p.s. Think about creating a cache of indexes mapping.

This is an example of a method to convert a **base model index to a child model index**:

```
const QModelIndex childModelIndex(const QModelIndex& baseModelIndex) const
{
  if (!baseModelIndex.isValid())
  {
    return QModelIndex();
  }

  int count = 0;
  const int row = baseModelIndex.row();

  for (QList<QAbstractTableModel*>::const_iterator it = m_models.begin();
    it != m_models.end(); it++)
  {
    const int currentCount = (*it)->rowCount();     

    if (row >= count && row < count + currentCount)
    {       
        return (*it)->index(row - count, 0);
    }

    count += currentCount;
}

ASSERT(false);

return QModelIndex();
```

}

This is an example of a method to convert a **child model index to a base model index**:

```
QModelIndex baseModelIndex(const QModelIndex& childModelIndex) const
{
    int row = childModelIndex.row();

    for (QList<QAbstractTableModel*>::const_iterator it = m_models.begin();
        it != m_models.end(); it++)
    {
        if (childModelIndex.model() == *it)
        {
            return index(row, ind.column());
        }

        row += (*it)->rowCount();
    }

    return QModelIndex();
}
```

Comment: How will the proposed approach solve conflicts between models. For example model1 returns "Foo" and model2 returns "Goo" from the `data()` function?

Comment: @vahancho No any conflicts. Method `data` has an index as an argument. Suppose a view asked for the data at inx(3,0): `base->data(idx)`. See the example above. Method `data` in the base model finds appropriate model. It is model2, calculates index in this model idx2(1,0) and returns `model2->data(idx2)`

Answer (score 4):

The KDE Frameworks project contains a module called [KItemModels](https://api.kde.org/frameworks/kitemmodels/html/index.html), which includes a class called [KConcatenateRowsProxyModel](https://api.kde.org/frameworks/kitemmodels/html/classKConcatenateRowsProxyModel.html). It does *exactly* what you want. The library is released every month as part of the [KDE Frameworks releases], the code is continuously [unit tested](https://build.kde.org/search/?q=kitemmodels&Jenkins-Crumb=983de9c00122c101d722d9fdad971a9f) on https://build.kde.org. All this is licensed under LGPL v2 or later.

Comment: This class is now part of Qt: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qconcatenatetablesproxymodel.html